# Changing the language of website dynamically using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I want to provide website viewers a dropdowm to select hindi or english language and dynamically change the language of website using codeigniter.How to implement that?

Comment: Thats a very broad question should do some research first

Comment: Take a read here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is by using templates and load language from database. You can keep all your language strings in tables , give the columns meaning full names or the names you want your variables to display your data into the view.

Then from drop down, trigger an event which should send an ajax request or redirect to your controller with language name or prefix or value as parameter. The controller should process that variable and using a switch of IF statement block , get the language data from database by calling respective function in the model or calling a dynamic function which brings the language data by name like

```
 $lang=$this->uri->segment(3); // or use query string
 $data['lang']=$this->language_model->getLangByName($lang);
```

send that data to your view and render it just by using indexes in the lang array

You can use [smarty template engine](http://www.smarty.net/) to make a dynamic view

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one language option for all post in admin panel. And according to dropdown click you will load your view. Please inform me if you need more help from us. I will do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have implemented changing language by user from front end. You will need to autoload the model or move functions to a helper and call them from there.
https://gist.github.com/jgmuchiri/92bb8b72b4d5a5cb02b7a88c1516edff